# converting video into a tensor in form of shape (TIME, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS)

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, data-science

I am converting video into video-frames using the given code

**Converting video into frames:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Playing video from file:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/home/administrator/Desktop/Projects/gait-     recognition/video/p008-n05.avi')
frames = []
try:
        if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data')
currentFrame = 0
while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
   # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
   name = './data/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.jpg'
print ('Creating...' + name)
cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
frames.append(frame)
# To stop duplicate images
currentFrame += 1
if ret == False:
   break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
imgs = np.array(frames)
```

which is giving me output as images in the form of a single multi-dimensional array. This is required here as

Create features from input frames in shape (TIME, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS)

```
spatial_features = net_pose.feed_forward_features(imgs)
```

Gives error as: SETTING AN ARRAY ELEMENT WITH A SEQUENCE

How should I modify the opencv code to get the desired shape of the tensor images?

Comment: I've tried you code and it is working. are you sure this is the right version of file that is giving you the  error message?

Comment: I need the size as (?,299,299,3). Are you getting the same?

Comment: I've tried with my own video. The frame shape is (356, 640, 3). So imgs shape is  (?,356, 640, 3)

Comment: Thanks i did some mistake with giving the path of the data. Anyway thanks a lot.